# How to open app on a specific tab bar? iOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am trying to have the app open on the third tab bar, not the first one. No matter what order I put the apps on the tab bar, the first one to the left always opens first. Can anyone help? Below is the tab bar code.

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];

UITableViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];


self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController3, viewController4, viewController1, viewController2,  nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

2, because array starts from 0;